# What is the minimum version of websphere application server (Network deployment) required for Mobile first server (version 7.1)?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, mobilefirst-server

I am planning to upgrade mobilefirst (MF) server from version 6.1 to 7.1. Current Websphere application server (WAS) network deployment (ND) version is 8.0.0.

Is it mandatory to upgrade WAS to 8.5.x before upgrading MF or MF 7.1 works fine with WAS 8.0.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 System Requirements page: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/r_supported_operating_systems_an.html.

Specifically at the Supported Software page: http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CMobile%20OS%7CSolaris%7CWindows&duComponentIds=S001

Where the following is listed for WAS ND as the Prerequisite Minimum:   7.0.0.35

Comment: Thanks.

I fount it here
http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88&osPlatform=Windows#sw-0

Under supported software.